# Sort a Java List<String> by passing a String and placing this String at last index

Tags: java, list, loops

I have a String anywhere in the list, and passing a string by parameter I need to place check if there's an element of the same, and put it at the end of the list, by reordering the other elements indexes.

It'd be something like this:

Initial list: "A", "B", "C", "D", "E"

Input parameter: "B"

If "B" in initial list: reorder the initial list.

Reordered list: "A", "E", "C", "D", "B"

```
 private void reorderList(List<String> list, String name) {
    for (int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++) {
        if (list.get(i).equals(name)) {

        }
    }
}
```

How can I do this?

Comment: @GhostCat Yeah, this is homework, and thanks! It already helped a lot!

Answer (score 1):

Pretty simple:

- first iterate the list, and check if there is a matching index
- if so, remember that index, and break the loop
- then: use [List.remove(int)](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/List.html#remove(int)) to **remove** that matching index
- finally: append your parameter (which matches the removed string!) to the end of the list

The trick is that aforementioned `remove()` will also shift any following elements to the left.

Answer (score 1):

Do not forget, that `List` could have multiple same elements. If so, then all of them should be moved to the end.

You could use `Iterator` to find and remove required elements at the same time. And after that, just add required number of elements to the end of the list. Using this approach, you iterate over the list only once, and this is **O(n)**.

```
private static void reorderList(List<String> list, String name) {
    Iterator<String> it = list.iterator();
    int total = 0;

    while (it.hasNext()) {
        if (name.equals(it.next())) {
            it.remove();
            total++;
        }
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < total; i++)
        list.add(name);
}
```

Comment: Alternatively you could create a second list and then do an AddAll.  The advantage is that the algorithm could handle multiple matching criteria instead of an exact match.

Comment: To be precise: you are making an assumption here. The requirements are not clear if only the first hit, or all matches should be moved to the end!

Comment: This is just example, but not complete (ready for copy-paste) solution

Answer (score 0):

Your List can check itself if it have an element that equals others.

It will use the "equals" method of the elements in it.

And for sorting, you can simply use the method from Collections. Or write your own comparator.

```
if (list.contains(name)) {
   Collections.sort(list);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Remember to use the tools provided by `java.util.List`.

- You can use `List.contains(Object)` to find if a String exists.
- Now, `List.indexOf(Object)` will return it's index in the list as an int.
- `List.remove(int)` will remove a given index from the list.
- `List.add(Object)`, will add at the end of the list.

Just a tip, you don't need the `for` if you use the functions I just mentioned. Also, remember that Strings are Objects.